# matlab: how do create a projection

Tags: matlab

I want to create a perspective projection of a 3D image onto the x,y plane with a focal length of 10 and a principal point (-1, -5).

I found:
view
viewmtx

But I do not get how to tell matlab that I want to use the x,y plane nor how to set the focal length? Can someone explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are not looking for the right functions.
The `view` function does only change the point of view on the current axis, while `viewmtx`return a transformation matrix.
You may want to do something similar to what it is discussed on this post [How do I draw a texture-mapped triangle in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274383), where `maketform` and `imtransform` are the key functions to get a plane image reprojected into another certain 3d plane.